# Facebook page update script

Tags: facebook, greasemonkey

I have a greasemonkey script that tries to make a status update when a facebook page loads.

But when I try to submit, I get the message:

> "This status update appears to be blank. Please write something or
>   attach a link or photo to update your status."

I am guessing that I am bypassing some input validation routine that is called when a real user types in the status.

Here is what I have beem trying.
Consider a FB page like: https://www.facebook.com/IFeakingLoveScience

```
function setmsg()
{
textHolder.focus();
var vntext=textHolder.value;
textHolder.value = postvalue;
textHolder.focus();
postbutton = document.getElementsByClassName( "_42ft _4jy0 _11b _4jy3 _4jy1" )[0];
postbutton.focus();
textHolder.focus();
setTimeout(postmsg, 4000); // Give the link in post value load.
}

function postmsg()
{
textHolder.focus();
textHolder = document.getElementsByClassName( "uiTextareaAutogrow input mentionsTextarea textInput" )[0];
textHolder.value = postvalue1 + "\n" +  postvalue2; // set the value again just in case that helps...

textHolder.focus();
postbutton.click();
}


setTimeout(setmsg, 1000); // give a sec for the page to load
```

Any clues?

Regards,
Manoj

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running your script on your 'Home' page on facebook, set your status update as the **value** of the hidden input named "xhpc_message" .

```
//set input value 
document.getElementsByName('xhpc_message')[0].value = 'yourstatusupdategoeshere';

//submit button click
document.getElementsByClassName('_42ft _4jy0 _11b _4jy3 _4jy1 selected')[0].click()
```